# How can I edit text in a UITextField when its inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to create a form like tableview, I have seen this a thousand times in other apps, so I figured it would be simple.

My attempt is below. I added a UITextField to the content view of a UITableViewCell. I have also tried implementing UITextFieldDelegate methods and setting selection style to none.

can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I am using the canned UITableViewController with a separate NSObject to handle the delegate and datasource methods, and a custom UITableViewCell subclass.

Right now when I tap the cells, they do not becomeFirstResponder, nothing happens at all.
I tried setting some breakpoints in setSelected, but it does not appear to be triggered.

My tableViewCell code

```
@implementation HSTableViewCell

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];

    NSDictionary *elements = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_textField);

    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_textField]|"
                                                                           options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:elements];

    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_textField]-|"
                                                                             options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:elements];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];

}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [self.textField removeFromSuperview];
    [self.contentView removeConstraints:self.contentView.constraints];
    self.textField = nil;
}


- (UITextField *)textField {
    if (!_textField) {
        _textField = [UITextField new];
        [_textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [_textField setPlaceholder:@"Test"];
    }
    return _textField;
}


@end
```

UITableViewController init

```
- (UITableViewController *)tableViewController {
    if (!_tableViewController) {
        _tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [_tableViewController.tableView setDataSource:self.tableViewDataManager];
        [_tableViewController.tableView setDelegate:self.tableViewDataManager];
        [_tableViewController.tableView registerClass:[HSTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifer];
    }
    return _tableViewController;
}
```

and UITableViewDelegate/Datasource

```
@implementation HSTableViewDataManger


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifer forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

If anyone is interested, the test project is below

This is VERY barebones, I am trying to isolate exactly what I need to achieve the desired behavior.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2396540/TextFieldInCellTest.zip

Comment: There is indeed a lot which does not really make sense, I will try to help you! To be honest, I think it would be easier if you used Storyboards to create this form, or do you intentionally want to know how it works programmatically?

Comment: What is the problem? What result does this code give you?

Comment: I do want to know how this works programmatically, but also this is just a slice of a much bigger app that I am helping with that cannot be converted to storyboards at this point.

Comment: @rdelmar nothing happens when tapping the cells. I see the placeholder text, but the textfield will not becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: I downloaded your test project,... Where did you get this code from or how did you think about this approach? It doesn't seem to be in line with any iOS standards?! Maybe it would be more fruitful for you to start with a tutorial on `UITableView`?!

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about @NikolasBurk, this is perfectly "in-line" with standards. it's called re-usable code.

Comment: This code doesn't have a lot of reusable elements though. For starters, it doesn't make much sense to declare a `HSTableViewDataManger` class that should serve as _delegate_ and _dataSource_ for a table view, which itself already belongs to a `UITableViewController`, since a `UITableViewController` by default is the _delegate_ and _dataSource_ of its table view...

Comment: We are starting to get off topic here. I could have made separate delegate and datasource objects, but then it wouldn't be a simple test app, I just wanted to make sure those methods were separated out for easy editing. The real issue at hand is allowing me to edit UITableViewCells.

Comment: No that wasn't my point, subclassing `UITableViewController` would be the far better option... Anyway, you need references to the textfields in the table view cells, otherwise you won't be able to access them or use their content. The next problem is that in your implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you return a normal instance of `UITableViewCell`, why bother then and having `HSTableViewCell.h/m` in your project when it is never used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why adding the text views in willMoveToSuperview doesn't work, but that's an unusual place to do that. You should put the code you have there into initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:, and you should delete the prepareForReuse method (the text fields will only be added once in the init method, so there's no need to delete them). That should give you text fields that are editable.

Comment: Thank you, I have been asking around ALL MORNING. No one was able to help me. I knew it had to be something stupid that I was missing.

Comment: @Kronusdark, you also need to change UITableViewCell *cell = ... in your data manager class to HSTableViewCell *cell = ... so you'll have access to any of your custom cell's properties (it is actually returning a HSTableViewCell, but you'll get an error if you try to access the text field).

Comment: Yea, I am aware. This was just a test spike to figure out that problem, the real code is a lot better.

Comment: Just implemented this into the real app, and it works! Thanks again.